# Warnings using glmer: pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations

Tags: r, glm

I'm testing preference over origin (native/ornamental) and flower colour (6 colours) in pollinators. To do so, I'm using a GLMM since data doesn't follow a normal distribution.

In the case of origin, everything is perfect, but when I try to run the model with colour as the predictor, I got 2 warnings.

My database is something like this:

| Date | Plant | Colour | Origin | Coleoptera | Syrphids | Apis | Solitary bees | Bumblebees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28-05-2021 | P. auriculata | Blue | Ornamental | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 13-02-2021 | C. persicum | Pink | Ornamental | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 07-05-2021 | L. rantonetti | Purple | Ornamental | 0.00 | 0.02 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0.01 |
| 18-05-2021 | C. radicans | Red | Ornamental | 0.00 | 0.01 | 0.14 | 0.08 | 0.01 |
| 18-05-2021 | A. mollis | White | Native | 0.00 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.03 |
| 09-04-2021 | T. officinale | Yellow | Native | 0.15 | 0.02 | 0.07 | 0.08 | 0.00 |

This is a very simplified summary of the table (only 1 plant of each colour and without repeating samplings). blue and pink plants don't have any visits, while plants with every other floral colour have visits.

I have 141 rows, 6 colours (Blue, Pink, Purple, Red, Yellow and White), several days and samplings of each species. Just for the record, I don't have registered any pollinator visiting blue or pink flowers (the columns are filled with zeros).

I'm using plants and date as random factors, so my code is this:

```
glmcol1 <- glmer(pol1+1 ~ Colour + (1|Date/Plant),
            family = Gamma(link = log), data = Database)
```

And I get these warnings:

> Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  :
> pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations

> Warning messages:
> 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, :  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
> 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues

I have 30 pollinator columns, and I didn't have these problems while testing preference over origin (the code stays the same, I only replaced Colour by Origin).

I eliminated Blue and Pink colours so I don't have rows filled with zeros. Now, the previous warnings no longer appear, but now I have this problem:

```
Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GHrule(0L), compDev = compDev,  : 
  pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations
```

I still think that one of the problems may be that I don't have enough samples (30 to 40 for each colour) to build the model. I could use the model while studying origin because the category only aggregated data in 2 groups (Native and Ornamental), so I had 60 to 70 values for each group. Can this be solved by changing the `glmerControl` function?

Comment: Solving these kinds of problems often requires access to the original data and/or a [mcve].  Categorical (factor) predictors with >2 levels are, in principle, no problem, but including levels with no observations might be a problem. If those colours are never visited, is there a reason you're including them in the data set for analysis?

Comment: Can you show `summary(Database)` ? I don't quite understand your statement " (the columns are filled with zeros)" for the absent colours; in the data table you've shown (and in your model), `Colour` is a categorical variable, so missing colours would be represented as the absence of any *rows* with that identifier ... ??

Comment: Okay, let's put it in context. I'm studying pollination in urban parks and I want to test if insects prefer (or refuse) any flower colour over others. This way, I'll be able to discuss if the plants in the park are useful for pollination.

Comment: Thus, these zeros are useful since they are the problem. I counted insects visiting plants and then I built a database with every plant and every pollinator filled with visit rates. This way, plants with any visits have a "zero" value for every interaction. I have replaced the table above with a more accurate one. The problem is not the database itself because I have used the same model for testing preference for origin (Native/Ornamental) and I didn't have any problems. I eliminated Pink and Blue values and now I have a different error which I explained above.

Comment: It's hard to debug this remotely.  Is there any chance you can provide a link to your data and/or a [mcve] ?